# when does setTimeout start executing in a inline <script>

Tags: javascript, html, timeout

say I have code like this

```
<html><body>
<bunch of html tags...>
<script>
     function myF()={};
     setTimeout(myF, 100);
</script>
<lots of more html goes here.....></body></html>
```

As I understand it, the script will be evaluated as the html is parsed.  But, in this case we have a setTimeout followed by lots of html parsing.  When will the timeout get to make its call?  Does it need to wait until all the html parsing is done before myF is finally called, or will myF be called when the timeout event occurs, even if there is more html parsing to accomplish?

Comment: [The world may never know...](http://i.imgur.com/JWwgeX1.gif) Not saying this is a pointless question, but if anyone wanted guarantees about when the callback would occur, they'd either use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), [`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [`$(function () { ... });`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: The timeout won't interrupt the current "thread", so wouldn't it wait until after the HTML is parsed? Anyway, are you asking just out of interest, or does it actually matter on your page for some reason? (In which case there's probably a better way to do whatever you're doing.)

Comment: yes, it matters for me, and yes there is probably a better way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, setTimeout() does *not* necessarily wait for DOMContentLoaded

If it did, we wouldn't have need for the `DOMContentLoaded` event, but if that's not enough to convince you, below is conclusive evidence:

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert("Window Loaded");
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert("DOM Content Loaded");
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(typeof jQuery == 'function' ? 'jQuery Loaded' : 'jQuery Not Loaded');
  }, 15);
</script>
<p>This content will be loaded before jQuery is fetched.</p>
<script>
  document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?' + Math.random() + '" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></' + 'script>');
</script>
<script>
  alert('Loaded after <script src="jquery.min.js">');
</script>
<p>This content will not be loaded until after jQuery is fetched.</p>
```

If it had to wait for `DOMContentLoaded`, you'd see

```
Loaded after <script src="jquery.min.js">
DOM Content Loaded
Window Loaded
jQuery Loaded
```

However (at least for me), a good portion of the time, the output is

```
jQuery Not Loaded
Loaded after <script src="jquery.min.js">
DOM Content Loaded
Window Loaded
```

Even though the parsing of HTML is single-threaded, it is blocked when `<script>` without `async` and `<link>` must pause to fetch the resource from the URL and execute the script or stylesheet respectively, which means there's a *race-condition* between the `DOMContentLoaded` event and `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 15)`.

Comment: In using DOMContentLoaded you're not testing quite what the OP asked. He asked about when "all the html parsing is done", but it's not inconceivable that the browser might run the timeout *after* parsing but *before* it runs the DOMContentLoaded event handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn alright, so I switch every reference I have to `document.onDOMContentLoaded` out with `window.onload` and it's the same answer. Would that make you happier? It doesn't matter whether it's `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded`. OP asked if it has to wait "until all the html parsing is done", and regardless of which event I use, the answer is still "no".

Comment: *"Would that make you happier?"* Nope. Because that is still testing the timing of *event handlers* being run and not the timing of when parsing is complete. (But as I commented up under the question, if this actually matters to the OP's code then there's probably a better way to be doing things.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I think you might be misunderstanding the question then (or maybe I am, but since I seem to be on the same page with @Clonkex, I'm thinking not), but the question is whether the callback for a `setTimeout` _must_ occur after the parsing is complete. If your argument is that `DOMContentLoaded` is the wrong event to indicate that, and that `onload` is more correct, it doesn't matter because `DOMContentLoaded` always happens before `onload` does, and the `setTimeout` calls back before either of those events occur.

Comment: Hmm.. I _kind of_ see your point, I find it extremely nitpicky, but your complaint is easily resolvable, hold on.

Comment: My idea to test it would be to put an inline script at the end of the body that assigns a value to a global variable, then access that variable from within the timeout. Because we know synchronous inline scripts are executed immediately before continuing parsing the document, so if the script is the last element the rest of the document must be parsed already.

Comment: P.S. I agree that a timeout may not wait for the DOMContentLoaded event handler - we agree on that part. I never said anything about `onload` - I don't think it is relevant.

Comment: @nnnnnn I replaced the `console.log()` with `alert()`, and you can visibly see when each of the paragraphs are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on that. `setTimeout` doesn't create an 'interrupt' so to speak, all it does it add the function to a queue that is checked when the browser decides to check it. This could be at the end of the thread loop, or it could be during HTML parsing.

Further reading on JavaScript timers: https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

---

The better (standard) way to wait until the HTML is finished parsing is like this:

```
<html><body>
<bunch of html tags...>
<script>
    function myF()={};
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myF);
</script>
<lots of more html goes here.....></body></html>
```

Or, using jQuery, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<bunch of html tags...>
<script>
    function myF()={};
    $(myF);
</script>
<lots of more html goes here.....></body></html>
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm trying to ensure my answer is correct. Do you have any references for how the rules for `setTimeout` actually work? I was answering based on experience but your tests seem to show it can run `setTimeout` in the middle of parsing.