# How to make sure that a javascript function is called first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a SaaS platform. I do not have access to the app.js file. However, I am able to upload my own JS in the footer. Currently, I have a function that on click tests to see if the menu is open by checking if the main wrapper has a class of menu-active. One of two things happen, if the menu is active I remove the overlay and if it is not I add a class of overlay. Unfortunately, the app.js, which I do not have access, uses toggleClass removes the menu-active class for CSS. Occasionally, the app.js removes the class which I am checking first and messes up my function. However, most of the time it works. How can I make my function click called first 100% of the time? I am using JQuery 2.1.1

```
$(".menu-toggle").first().click(function () {
            if (!$("#wrapper").hasClass("menu-active")) {
                $("#wrapper").find("div:first").addClass("overlay");
            }
            if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("menu-active")) {
              $("#wrapper").find("div:first").removeClass("overlay");
            }
        });
```

Comment: That seems hacky to workaround a behavioral conflict between two scripts. Why can't you have access to `app.js` file to fix it instead?

Comment: Mgmt. and SaaS. believe me I am frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrapping the check in a `setTimeout`:

```
$(".menu-toggle").first().click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$("#wrapper").hasClass("menu-active")) {
            $("#wrapper").find("div:first").addClass("overlay");
        }
        if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("menu-active")) {
            $("#wrapper").find("div:first").removeClass("overlay");
        }
    }, 1);
});
```

That *should* cause the check to happen after the browser has updated the DOM.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to switch the if statements bc adding a set timer would delay my function?

Comment: @user3562836 Possibly, that depends on whether you expect the class to have already been removed (and it sometimes isn't). or you expect the class to be _about to be_ removed (and it sometimes already is). The `setTimeout` doesn't delay the check by any noticeable amount (1ms to be exact, although you could set that to 0 with the same result), but it does ensure the code is executed later. Hopefully it should be after any classes are added or removed.

Comment: Does using setTimeout inherently say hey what for the other JS to execute?

Comment: Pretty much it just puts the timeout into a queue that's checked at the end of the normal JS execution, but it's also [not as clear-cut as that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712485/2288578) and might not work. Just try it and see. It might work, it might not. If it doesn't work let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Make the following,

```
<link rel="preload" href="path-to-your-script.js" as="script">
<script>
   var scriptPriority = 
    document.createElement('script');
    scriptPriority.src = 'path-to-your-script.js'; 
    document.body.appendChild(scriptPriority);
</script>
```

About: Link rel Preload
Link rel preload is method that is used by a few developers, its something that almost nobody known and its use to give priority to a script or link css.

More info in:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: How often have you used it?

Comment: I only use it to give priority to my principal js and css style rules, no more!

Comment: This won't do anything. All this will do is ensure one script is loaded before another, not that a class will be added or removed before a click callback is run.