# custom elements & connectedCallback() : wait for parent node to be available before firing a function

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-element

I'm using custom elements, which are very nice.
But I'm facing a problem :

When the *connectedCallback()* function is called, it seems that the node is not yet at its place in the DOM, thus I cannot access its parents - and I need them.

```
class myElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tracklist =    undefined;
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        this.render();
    }
    render(){

        this.tracklist = this.closest('section');

        // following code requires this.tracklist!
        // ...
    }

window.customElements.define('my-element', myElement);
```

How could I be sure the parent nodes are accessible before calling render() ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [textContent empty in connectedCallback() of a custom HTMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498581/textcontent-empty-in-connectedcallback-of-a-custom-htmlelement)

Comment: This is a bad component design. You should not rely on your component residing in a certain DOM context. You could for example append it to a `documentFragment` -  in this case it wouldn't even have *any* parent nodes!

Answer (score 3):

Long answer moved to a single StackOverflow answer where all updates and new knowlegde is kept: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952159/2520800

Comment: I've had cases where even that's not enough. Sometimes setTimeout (with 0ms or without argument) would be enough, some other times it's not enough of a delay. When I set the argument to 1ms, I never have the issue. This seem to go along with this answer from another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182869/10294974

Comment: I have added a Note

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `connectedCallback` cannot access other elements in relation to itself when it hasn't been parsed yet. This kind of makes sense if you consider that a *custom-element* has to be able to live **anywhere** in the DOM without being dependent on another element. So if there were no parent to be selected, the element would probably not work properly.

A way to do this is to modify the `render` method to take an argument which will set the `tracklist` property dynamically to the custom element. Then select the `my-element` element from the DOM and look for the `section`.

Then use the [`customElements.whenDefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) method to connect the `section` and `my-element` together whenever the custom element is ready. This method returns a Promise that resolves whenever the custom element is defined and gives you the ability to execute a callback.

See example below:

```js
// Do something whenever the element is ready.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Wait for the document to load so the DOM has been parsed.
  window.customElements.whenDefined('my-element').then(() => {
    const myElement = document.querySelector('my-element');

    // Only do something if the element exists on the page.
    if (myElement !== null) {
      const tracklist = myElement.closest('section');
      myElement.render(tracklist);
      console.log(myElement.tracklist);
    }

  });

});

// Create element.
class myElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tracklist = null;
    }
    render(tracklist){
        this.tracklist = tracklist;
        // following code requires this.tracklist!
        // ...
    }
}

// Define element.
window.customElements.define('my-element', myElement);
```

```html
<section>
  <my-element></my-element>
</section>
```

If I have been unclear or you have questions, please let me know.

Have a nice day!

Comment: *It seems that the connectedCallback cannot access other elements in relation to itself.* You might want to add "when it hasn't been parsed yet" to that bold statement. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498581/textcontent-empty-in-connectedcallback-of-a-custom-htmlelement

Comment: An why do you give a totally different (and better) answer 2 hours earlier?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663678/how-to-have-a-connectedcallback-for-when-all-child-custom-elements-have-been-c

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added your quote. About the former comment: although both cases seem similar, OP wants to select a parent and the other thread tries to select a child from a custom element. The `slot` element is also a solution to the problem here, and if you think it would be better, I'd be happy to add it.

Comment: But my initial emphasis is on creating custom elements which do not worry about other elements in the DOM, or even its own content. You pointed out the missing `parsedCallback` method. And the reason for its absence makes sense. Native elements don't have this behavior either and don't modify siblings, parents, textContent or any other nodes when they are initialized. It is up to you to modify it whenever you need it and can do that outside of the elements. However this is my conclusion taken from the workings of native and custom elements. I'd be happy to hear your thoughts about this.

Comment: Another issue (after looking more closely at your code) whenDefined is executed once the element is defined in the customElementRegistry.. so what happens if there is no ``my-element`` in the DOM? Problem with JSFiddle (and maybe with inline code here as well) is that the JS code is executed **after** the HTML code. (in JSFiddle) Put all JS in a <script> tag at the start of the HTML and you get different behaviour

Comment: Very true, as that is with any kind of JS that selects elements from the DOM **before** the HTML in the body. Wrapping the code inside the `whenDefined` callback in a `window.onload` listener and checking  if `my-element` exists would solve that problem. If OP decides to include the JS at the top of the document, then he would have to wait for the `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event no matter what.

Comment: Interesting additional read on when things happen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712379/when-does-settimeout-start-executing-in-a-inline-script

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out but seems like a `Promise` might work:

```js
// DomReady.js
class DomReady extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.domReadyPromise = new Promise(resolve => (this.domReadyResolve = resolve));
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.domReadyResolve();
  }

  domReady() { return this.domReadyPromise; }
}
```

```js
// ParentCustom.js
class ParentCustom extends DomReady {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    ...
  } 
}
```

```js
// ChildCustom.js
class ChildCustom extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback() {
    await document.querySelector('parent-custom').domReady();
  }
}
```