# Web Components accessing innerHTML in connectedCallBack

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

```
class Form extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this)
        console.log(this.innerHTML)

    }
}

customElements.define("my-form", Form);
```

I'm trying to access the innerHTML now for `console.log(this)` if I expand it in the console innerHTML is set but when I try `console.log(this.innerHTML)` it logs nothing.

how come even in the connectedCallback i cant access anything inside my tags.

ultimately what I'm trying to do is

```
class Form extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        let inputCounter = 0
        for (let i of this.querySelectorAll("input")) {
            this[inputCounter] = i
            inputCounter++
        }
    }
}

customElements.define("my-form", Form);
```

but I cant do it because I cant access anything inside the element.

Comment: "it logs nothing" - what do you expect to see in this case?

Comment: Im sorry the html code is
     <my-form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </my-form>

Comment: innerHTML: "\n        <input type=\"text\">\n        <input type=\"text\">\n        <input type=\"text\">\n        <input type=\"text\">\n        <input type=\"text\">\n        <input type=\"submit\">\n    "
innerText: "     "

this is the log for innHTML in console.log(this)

Answer (score 5):

#### WTF `innerHTML` is an empty string?!?

```html
<script>
 customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback(){
    console.log( this.innerHTML.length , " chars in innerHTML" );
  }
 });
</script>

<my-component>Hello Web Component World!</my-component>
```

#### HTML only example

Key is to understand *when* DOM was parsed

In this script below, everyone will agree the first `console` logs **0**, because it executed ***before*** the remaining DOM was parsed.

```html
<script>
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div").length , "divs");
</script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<script>
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div").length , "divs");
</script>
```

##### Logs:

```
0 divs
3 divs
```

#### Web Component `connectedCallback`

The same applies to the `connectedCallback`, it **fires/fired on the opening tag**

So like the *first* `<script>` tag in the first example,
**all following DOM (3 DIVs in lightDOM) is NOT parsed yet**

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const LOG = () => console.log(this.id, this.children.length, "divs");
        LOG();
        setTimeout( () => LOG() );
    }
  });
</script>

<my-component id="Foo">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</my-component>
```

##### Logs:

```
Foo 0 divs
Foo 3 divs
```

I repeat: the `connectedCallback` fires on the **opening** tag.

That means all **attributes** are available ON the Web Component,
but **NOT** its three `<div>` child elements IN lightDOM.

##### Wait till lightDOM is parsed

Simplest method to get that lightDOM content is to delay execution till the **Event Loop** is *empty* again, and you know ***more***  (and *most likely* ***all***) of your lightDOM was parsed.

###### Background knowledge:

[Youtube: Jake Archibald on the web browser event loop, setTimeout, requestAnimationFrame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

> BUT!
> Because the Event Loop can be(come) empty when the (large) DOM is still being parsed!
>
> This gets you the *next* **N** elements parsed, not ALL elements in a (**large**) lightDOM!
>
> Rough tests show around N=1000 (1000 lightDOM elements) are safe to work with.
> but your mileage may vary for complex CPU consuming elements
> Maybe just increase to 1 millisecond setTimeout delay

#### requestAnimationFrame (rAF)

`requestAnimationFrame` can also be used. Read!:
[setTimeout vs requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523029/settimeout-vs-requestanimationframe)
But because `setTimeout` triggers **later** you know ***more* N** elements were parsed.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
  // ... your code
});
```

[Do watch Jakes video before using rAF!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

##### Potential pitfall: the `attributeChangedCallback`

!!! The `attributedChangedCallback` fires **BEFORE** the `connectedCallback` for ***every*** `attribute` defined as an observed attribute in `static get observedAttributes()`

If none of those Observed attributes exist on the Element in the DOM,  `attributeChangedCallback` will **not** execute.

#### get ALL children - parsedCallback()

For getting **all** Child nodes, there is `parsedCallback()` by WebReflection.
But LOC (Lines Of Code) now goes from 1 to 77 :
https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element/blob/master/index.js
Maybe good to add this to your own BaseClass.
But for small components you are adding more overhead than a `setTimeout` or `rAF` takes.

##### Lifecycle methods in Lit, Stencil, FAST, Hybirds and [61 other tools](https://webcomponents.dev/blog/all-the-ways-to-make-a-web-component/)

Almost all Tools add their own `parsedCallback` like lifecycle methods:

- https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle
- https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#custom-element-lifecycle

Saving *unexperienced* developers headaches

Biggest drawback; you learn a Tool, not the Technology.

#### Old Mozilla/FireFox bug

Closed bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673811

Up until **Spring 2021** there where issues with `connectedCallback` in FireFox always firing **late**, so all above mentioned issues never happened in FireFox... but do now.

#### What the experts said

Experts discussion going back to **2016** is here:
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/551

#### Escaping all issues

When Web Components are **defined AFTER DOM was created** you don't have any of these `connectedCallback` issues; ***because all DOM was parsed***

So a `<script defer src="yourelement.js">` does the job; **but** will run **after** all DOM is created,
your components are now created (very) late. So you now have to deal with (more) FOUCs.

[image]

##### Online IDEs

Note CodePen, JSFiddle and all those online IDEs **run the JavaScript *AFTER*** the DOM is created!
So you never experience any issues there.
Test your code outside of these online IDEs before you take it to production!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Danny '356CSI' Engelmans answer, there is an npm package available that adds this missing `parsedCallback`, and instead of relying on the event loop (which might be problematic in edge cases (none of which I could tell off the top of my head)) tries to make sure children are available by using some more complex heuristics like checking if the custom element has a `nextSibling` (in which case it must have been fully parsed): https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element

Using a timeout instead of those complex heuristics may be preferrable in case you need to [support really old browsers like IE 6-10](https://caniuse.com/mutationobserver).

If you're using npm you can simply install it using

```
import HTMLParsedElement from 'html-parsed-element';
```

Usage goes like

```js
customElements.define(
  'custom-element',
  class extends HTMLParsedElement {
    parsedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = 'always <strong>safe</strong>!';
      console.log(this.parsed); // always true here
    }
  }
);

// or use as a mix-in
const {withParsedCallback} = HTMLParsedElement;
customElements.define(
  'other-element',
  withParsedCallback(class extends HTMLElement {
    parsedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = 'always <strong>safe</strong>!';
      console.log(this.parsed); // always true here
    }
  })
);
```

This small repository was created following a [discussion over on github](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/551) in which I contributed [the blue print](https://gist.github.com/franktopel/5d760330a936e32644660774ccba58a7) of what Andrea Giammarchi (also the author of a well-known (and well-working) [custom elements polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements)) has published as [`HTMLParsedElement`](https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element).

Answer (score 0):

I have spent many hours on this problem, and here is simple solution that works well.

All you need to do is wrap `connectedCallback`  in `window.requestAnimationFrame`

```js
class Form extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      let inputCounter = 0

      for (let i of this.querySelectorAll("input")) {
        this[inputCounter] = i
        inputCounter++
      }
    })
  }
}

customElements.define("my-form", Form);
```

Using this method, you will always have all child nodes available.

Comment: See my updated answer, I don't think ``rAF`` gets you **all** child nodes; since ``setTimeout`` _fires_ later than ``rAF``, ``setTimeout`` will actually get you _more_ (not all) nodes.