# How can I catch children added to a web component before first render?

Tags: javascript, html, native-web-component

I'm attempting to create a web component that modifies the behavior and style of its child elements. However, I'd like to do this modification before the first render, so that no flickering occurs.

Below is a (hopefully) small example of a web component that this is intended to create content (identified by the `content` class) that is hidden when the user clicks the header (identified by the `trigger` class).

```js
"use strict";

customElements.define(
  "shrinkable-content",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    static observedAttributes = ["shrunk"];

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const triggers = Array.from(this.getElementsByClassName("trigger"));
        const contents = Array.from(this.getElementsByClassName("content"));
        if (typeof this.shrunk === "undefined") {
          this.shrunk = false;
        }
        contents.forEach( (content) => {
          content.oldStyle = content.style.display;
          if (this.shrunk) content.style.display = "none";
        });
        triggers.forEach((trigger) => {
          trigger.style.cursor = "pointer";
          trigger.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            this.shrunk = !this.shrunk;
            contents.forEach((content) => {
              content.style.display = this.shrunk ? "none" : content.oldStyle;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      if (name === 'shrunk') this.shrunk = (newValue === "true") || (newValue === "");
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>HTML + JavaScript</title>
    <script src="./shrinkable-content.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <shrinkable-content shrunk>
          <button class="trigger">Alpha Item</button>
          <ul class="content">
            <li>Item One</li>
            <li>Item Two</li>
          </ul>
        </shrinkable-content>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice the `setTimeout()` call early in the `connectedCallback()` function. I added that because without it, the function is called before the children are added/mounted. However, it also delays the execute until *after* the first render, resulting in flickering.

For some more context: I'm *really* trying to avoid the 'shadow' DOM approach here; it really goes against the design principals I'm trying to follow.

**Edit:** There have been a couple solutions presented for the 'shrinking' feature (which *is appreciated*), but the real question here is about the lifecycle of web components; The example is just to help discuss the issue/question.

Comment: I believe you can add some styles that target the webcomponent before it's mounted:


shrinkable-content .trigger {
 /*styles*/
}

shrinkable-content .content {
 /*styles*/
}

You should add these styles before your js file.

Comment: I think the problem would be that the style is conditional. The `shrunk` attribute can change whether the content is initially hidden or rendered.

Comment: You can write styles with respect to attributes, shrinkable-content[shrunk] {/*styles*/). Here you could write styles that apply when the attribute is present and overrides styles for when attribute is not present. But it could be that i'm not understanding the issue properly.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you. Note: Yogi saying ``setTimeout`` is _code smell_, does not understand what ``connectedCallback`` in combination with lightDOM does.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I'm not sure what the sentence "Yogi saying setTimeout is code smell, does not understand what connectedCallback in combination with lightDOM does" is trying to convey.

Comment: @Hackerbyday Interesting. I'll keep this in mind for the future as a potential work-around. However, my question is less about the shrinking feature specifically; it is more about understanding the life cycles of web components (edited my question to make this clearer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are *rebuilding* default HTML `<details>` and `<summary>`

```html
<details>
  <summary>Alpha Item</summary>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

Or wrapped in a more advanced Web Component, handling closing other opened `<details>`

```html
<style>
  summary { font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer }
  details[open] { background: beige  }
</style>

<details-accordion>
  <details open>
    <summary>Summary 1</summary>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Summary 2</summary>
      "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Summary 3</summary>
      "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </details>
</details-accordion>

<script>
customElements.define(
  'details-accordion', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.onclick = e => [...this.children].forEach(d => 
                                    !e.ctrlKey 
                                      && 
                                    d.toggleAttribute("open", e.target == d));
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the code I provided and the question I asked doesn't expose that. The issue is with when `connectedCallback` is executed, which is included in both the samples and referred to in my question. Is there something else that would highlight this better?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949141/web-components-accessing-innerhtml-in-connectedcallback/70952159#