# Edit an attribute of the pseudo-class ":host"

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, shadow-dom

In an Angular application, I want to edit the attribute `border-top` of the pseudo-class `:host` applied to the component `p-table-row`, which is a component from a [porsche library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@porsche-design-system/components-angular/v/3.9.0), so I can't edit it directly.

A picture is worth a thousand word, so here it is :
[image]

I tried the following CSS selectors but none work.

```css
p-table-row {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important; // cf. image above
}

p-table-body {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

:host(p-table-body) {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

:host(p-table-row) {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

p-table-row :host {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

I am also willing to use a query selector to edit this attribute, but likewise I don't know how to select the class :host.

Sorry I can't provide a stackblitz, as I can't get it to work with the library I am using.

---

EDIT: I managed to do it after tweaking the [answer from Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77711012/6271234).

**CSS:** set `border-top` as I want it to be.

```
p-table p-table-row:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid $color-porsche-red-dark;
}
```

**Typescript:** set native `border-top` to null so my css takes precedence (just setting it to the value I want does not work). Note that `cssRules[0]` refers to `:host` (I probably should select it by its name but whatever).

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document
        .querySelectorAll('p-table p-table-row:first-of-type')
        .forEach(el => (el.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets[0].cssRules[0] as CSSStyleRule).style.borderTop = null);
    }, 100);
  }
```

It works, but the downside is that I need a `setTimeout`, which I set to a maximum of 100 because above you can see the css being applied, even thought it is just in a blink. Also sometimes the `setTimeout` is not enough, so I guess there is no perfect solution here.

Comment: The meaning of `:host` changes accordingly to which component style you put it in. If you are setting the style of `p-table-row`, did you try just `:host { ... } `?

Comment: To my understanding, here `:host` would mean the host of my component, which is not the same as the host of `p-table-row`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experienced developers use `!important` only when required.
Remind me not to buy a Porsche.

You can probably only inject CSS into the existing shadowRoot to overrule earlier STYLE definitions in shadowRoot (but only in `open` shadowRoots)

```
.querySelector("p-table-row")
  .shadowRoot
    .append(
       Object.assign(document.createElement("STYLE"),{
         innerHTML: `:host{1px solid red!important}`
       })
    );
```

Note: or dig into existing stylesheets, like you added to your question

Comment: I could not make your code work but It lead me to a similar solution, so I will flag it as the accepted answer, thank you. I agree about `!important`, but the developers who coded this lib definitely are better than 99% of developers.

Comment: Please append your code to the answer.

Comment: I did before I answered you, editing my original comment.

Comment: For less than (about) 500 nodes in your ligthDOM, you can set the ``setTimeout`` to **0**. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949141/web-components-accessing-innerhtml-in-connectedcallback/70952159#70952159